# jedi-vim and YCM python indentation

Tags: python, jedi-vim

I'm using YouCompleteMe vim plugin for Python dev. YCM uses jedi-vim to autocomplete python code. However, I want to configure python indentation to 2 spaces not 4 (Google Python style). How can I do this? I tried add python.vim in /ftplugin and set tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2. but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

this solved the problem: http://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=174117 so adding an after/ftplugin/language.vim  in .vim folder