# Change color settings in you complete me

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vim-syntax-highlighting

I installed You Complete Me with the help of Vundle in vim. The first time I used it, the suggested words were completely unreadable. They had a dark purple background and a black font color. Then I saw [this post on quora](http://www.quora.com/Vim/How-do-I-change-color-of-the-preview-window-in-You-Complete-Me-for-Vi) and changed my .vimrc now. My .vimrc looks like this at the moment.

```
set tabstop=2
highlight Comment ctermfg=lightblue
highlight Pmenu ctermfg=2 ctermbg=3 guifg=#ffffff guibg=#000000

set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'

Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
```

Unfortunately the suggested words are display like this

[image]

I can't read that very well and would like to change it but don't know how. I thought that my current settings would give me white foreground and black background.

After installing this Plugin I also have 4 instead of 2 indents.. I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538951/jedi-vim-and-ycm-python-indentation), but it didn't serve me. How can I change this?

Comment: Please don't include multiple unrelated problems in one question.

Answer (score 21):

You are editing the settings for the GUI not for the command line.

`highlight Pmenu ctermfg=15 ctermbg=0 guifg=#ffffff guibg=#000000`

This would give you a black background and a white foreground in both gvim and the command line.

[Color chart for vim colors](http://www.calmar.ws/vim/256-xterm-24bit-rgb-color-chart.html)

Edit: corrected spelling

Comment: this gives me black font color and dark grey background

Comment: Actually I guess I should clarify what you are asking. Are you asking about when the option is selected or when it is in the dropdown?

Comment: Thank you! You made my day! This answer is exactly what I was looking for! :D (btw. https://stackoverflow.com/q/60590376/544721 ctermxx/guixx variables difference for those who like to know)

Answer (score 6):

You've just changed the definition of `Pmenu`, the highlighting of normal items. There's also `PmenuSel` for the selected item, which I suspect is what's on your screenshot. (There are even more, check `:help hl-Pmenu` for the complete list.

Also, note that for those settings to be effective, they must come *after* any `:colorscheme` command. I didn't see such in your posted `~/.vimrc`, so choosing a different colorscheme (some ship with Vim, many more can be downloaded from [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/) or elsewhere) might be an alternative to tweaking all these colors yourself.

Comment: As long as you don't dynamically switch colorschemes, just put the `:hi ...` commands below the line that selects the `:colorscheme` in your .vimrc. If you'd like to switch colorschemes on the fly, you additionally need to execute the `:hi` command(s) via `:autocmd ColorScheme * hi ...`, too.