# what is the difference between cterm color and gui color?

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I am customizing my own color scheme for Vim but I don't know when should I configure ctermfg/ctermbg variable and guifg/guibg variable because I didn't see any differences between them at all. Is there any difference between them?

Can any one give me an illustrative example of how to use them ?
Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> I didn't see any differences between them at all

`ctermxx` is used by console version of Vim (when `set notermguicolors`). `guixx` is used in GVim, or in console if `set termguicolors`, and the console is capable of TrueColor, obviously. Hence you must test it in different programs to see the difference.

Also, some colors could be the same or very close to each other, e.g. "blue" is "blue" both in GUI and console.

> Can any one give me an illustrative example of how to use them?

```
hi Normal guifg=#1034a6 guibg=#f5f5dc ctermfg=19 ctermbg=230
```

Should look very similar but still a little different in GUI and console

For symbolic colors names see `:h cterm-colors` and `$VIMRUNTIME/rgb.txt`. The cheat sheet of 256 color indexes for console is available [here](https://jonasjacek.github.io/colors/).

Answer (score 2):

The separate pairs allow you to specify different colors for a terminal (which may limit you to a fixed-sized palette of colors, usually 16 or 256) and a GUI (which typically provides a much larger palette or even direct access to any color your display can handle).

For example, if you start a session in your terminal using `vi some_file.txt`, then `ctermfg` and `ctermbg` would be used. If you start an instance of `gvim` (which opens its own window independent of your terminal emulator), then `guifg` and `guibg` are used instead.

Comment: If there is a line like this what does it mean: hi StatusLine guifg=blue guibg=darkgray gui=none ctermfg=blue ctermbg=gray term=none cterm=none