# vimrc color scheme not changing background

Tags: vim, background-color, color-scheme

Ok, I know this question has been asked a lot, but the answers haven't helped me. When I change my colorscheme to `onedark`, the background doesn't change correctly, it should be darker, but it's not.

The vim I have:

[image: The vim I have]

What it should look like:

[image: What it should look like]

Does anyone know what could be happening?

For context [this](https://github.com/joshdick/onedark.vim) is the colorscheme and that is my `vimrc` file:

```
syntax on

set visualbell t_vb=
set tabstop=4 softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set smartindent
set nu
set nowrap
set smartcase
set noswapfile
set nobackup
set undodir=~/.vim/undodir
set undofile
set incsearch
set colorcolumn=80
set mouse=a
set t_Co=256
set background=dark

highlight Normal ctermbg=NONE
highlight nonText ctermbg=NONE
highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=0 guibg=lightgrey

call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

Plug 'joshdick/onedark.vim'
Plug 'jremmen/vim-ripgrep'
Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plug 'leafgarland/typescript-vim'
Plug 'vim-utils/vim-man'
Plug 'lyuts/vim-rtags'
Plug 'kien/ctrlp.vim'
Plug 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
Plug 'mbbill/undotree'
Plug 'SirVer/ultisnips'
Plug 'honza/vim-snippets'

call plug#end()

colorscheme onedark

if executable('rg')
    let g:rg_derive_root='true'
endif

let g:ctrlp_user_command = ['.git/', 'git --git-dir=%s/.git ls-files -oc --exclude-standard']
let mapleader = "\<Space>"
let g:newtrw_browse_split=2
let g:newtrw_banner = 0
let g:newtrw_winsize = 25

let g:ctrlp_use_caching = 0

nnoremap <leader>h :wincmd h<CR>
nnoremap <leader>j :wincmd j<CR>
nnoremap <leader>k :wincmd k<CR>
nnoremap <leader>l :wincmd l<CR>
nnoremap <leader>u :UndotreeShow<CR>
nnoremap <leader>pv :wincmd v<bar> :Ex <bar> :vertical resize 30<CR>
nnoremap <leader>ps :Rg<SPACE>
nnoremap <silent> <leader>+ :vertical resize +5<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <leader>- :vertical resize -5<CR>

nnoremap <silent> <leader>gd :YcmCompleter GoTo<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <leader>gf :YcmCompleter FixIt<CR>
```

Comment: Do you run Vim in a terminal emulator or is it the GVim/MacVim GUI? Anyway, use [the issue tracker](https://github.com/joshdick/onedark.vim/issues).

Comment: [what is the difference between cterm color and gui color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60590376/what-is-the-difference-between-cterm-color-and-gui-color)

Comment: @romainl when I use Mac vim it works, but it doesn't when I use a terminal emulator. Side note: I've used Iterm2 and the default terminal, they both don't work.

Comment: Did you consider reading the troubleshooting section of their README?

Answer (score 0):

Use this link https://github.com/navarasu/onedark.nvim.git or write this

Plug 'https://github.com/navarasu/onedark.nvim.git'

in your vimrc. You can also choose different themes of onedark.